# How do I get my garage door open without prying it with a hanger?

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a lift master and I programmed the remote and left it in my vehicle. I forgot to program the key pad and defaulted to factory settings. How do I get my garage door open with out prying it with a hanger? Is there master password? Or can I hotwire the outside control panel?

Comment: You won't be able to 'hotwire' the keypad at all. Most keypads are wireless (since you're talking about programming, I'll assume this is brand new), and are all digital. They have to send a special unique code (an encrypted "open" command probably - I'm not sure *exactly* how they do it), and the only way they'll send that code is if you enter the right sequence of buttons. An un-programmed keypad won't even know what command it *should* send, even if you could somehow 'trick' it into sending it (which you can't anyway). Good for protecting from intruders, but not your current situation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an entrance door to your garage (either to the interior of your house, or the exterior), there should be a key-based garage door release on the outside of your garage. You would obviously need the key for this, but it would release the garage door without resorting to prying it with a hanger or another similar hack.

It is also very typical to have a hardwired button available inside your house or next to an entrance door of the garage.

If not I doubt you can easily hotwire the control panel and instead would need to figure out how to pull the release cable.  Lucky for you there are a ton of YouTube videos on how to do this. [Here's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMjtLA23sH0).

Answer (score 1):

Opening it with a coat hanger has got to be a million times easier than "hotwiring" the control panel.

So this is a garage with no doors and no windows? Completely sealed except for the main door?

Liftmaster has a web site which allows you to submit your registered email address and they will email you back a code. If you have not registered the opener the coat hangar is probably the way to go.

Also, if the remote in your car is "programmed" and presumably working, why are you not using it?

Comment: Because it's in the car, inside the garage.  Which means there must be another door out of the garage, unless he hit the button to close the door then ran out as it was closing.  May have better luck with that door.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek Or maybe its at the mechanics, who knows. That is what we are trying to figure out: what bizarre combination of errors has led to this post.

Comment: Actually, he says so in the first line - well about it being left in the vehicle at least.  We can assume by the context that the vehicle isn't accesible.  Either it's someplace else, in which case, why bother asking the question - just go get the vehicle.  Or it's in the garage.